# How to open index.html page when page in refresh in SPA Application using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React and React-router in my SPA. When user navigates from one view to another, URL gets appended with hash (e.g #/broker/5e1f75c6-5a62-4d60-860c-1dd0d5ff8644?_k=w5wn3g) and this is expected and works fine for all views.

However when user refreshes page on any view, I want React-router to redirect to Index Route irrespective of view the user in. Is there any configuration I can do in React-router to setup this?

Right now React-router tries to navigate to matching route view. I just want to redirect to Index route/index.html without any server side redirects. Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can write an `onEnter` in route configuration and add required checks

Comment: Can you add your `index.js` or whichever file you have setup the history in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` (or `push`) function of `react-router`. Call your history singleton's `replace` method after you set up the history.

## Example

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';

hashHistory.replace('/');
```

## References

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: on calling hashHistory.replace('/'); on page load, regardless of hash present in URL, it opens Index route. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Did this help you find a solution? If so please consider marking your question answered. Or, if you need more help, let me know!

Comment: Underneath the down arrow is a check mark you can click. Also you may choose to up or down vote answers there.